# 404 error when redirection to a link codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have hosted a site in my live server for testing.but i have used  code to get to the specific controllers  in my system .It is working well in my localhost but in my live server it  doesnt work

Url are as follows

In local

a  localhost:55/axxxx

b   69.1xx.xxx.xxx/~username/axxxx/axxxx

when calling a controller using a it works well but when calling the controller using b it  gives me 404 error

here is my co`index.php/Authenticaton/authenticate">

```
                <p>
                    <label for="login">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username or email" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name='password' placeholder="Password" required> 
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit"   id="login"  class="btn-1" value="Continue">
                </p>       
            </form>`
```

Pleas help me in this situation

Sorry for the Bad English

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Some more details would help, but you can start by checking your application/config/config.php file, see if you are using the correct Base URL.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work while putting index.php before controller name, if so take a look at your htaccess.This might work:

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

might be base_url is pointing to different location.
Put this instead of base_url:

```
 $root  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
 $config['base_url']    = "$root";
```